# Single XML configuration for Doctrine

Tags: xml, doctrine

According to the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html#simplified-xml-driver):

> You can add a global file and add multiple entities in this file.

What I tried is:

```
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\SimplifiedXmlDriver(array("orm-xml"));
$driver->setGlobalBasename('global');

// ...

$em->getClassMetadata('something_Application');
```

I have a directory named `orm-xml` and it contains a file `global.orm.xml` as the documentation suggests. When I try to run my script I get:

```
uncaught exception: No mapping file found named 'omething_Application.orm.xml' for class 'something_Application'.
```

The first thing I noticed that the error message eats the first caharacter of the classname. And there is the main problem: it is trying to read config on a one-xml-per-class basis, why doesn't it use the global file I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was something that examples did not show: the `addPaths` method:

```
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\SimplifiedXmlDriver(array("orm-xml"));
$driver->setGlobalBasename('global');
$driver->addPaths(array("orm-xml"));
```

Note that I was thinking that the constructor's parameter is for this. I still don't know what it is really for.